# Can't find module when generating discovery docs for google app engine in python

Tags: python, ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-module

I am trying to generate Google App Engine discovery docs for iOS and it's giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/usr/local/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 561, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 557, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 443, in _GenDiscoveryDocCallback
    application_path=args.application)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 302, in _GenDiscoveryDoc
    application_path=application_path)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 187, in GenApiConfig
    module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=base_service_class_name)
ImportError: No module named default
```

I am running the following command

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/endpointscfg.py get_discovery_doc --format roc 
default.rock
```

Also, the following is my app.yaml file. So I am trying to generate the discovery docs for my default module. Also, I have a cloud endpoint api called RockApi in a file called rock.py so what should be my ServiceClass. Like above I have default.rock. Is this correct?

```
application: rocky-1191
version: pre-alpha-002
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'module' refers to the Python module your class resides in, not the App Engine module. See the [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/endpoints_tool#generating_a_discovery_doc_from_a_backend_api) for examples.